# Double the variables in move script (Google)

Tags: google-apps-script

For my work I am trying to automatically move a marked line to a 'Historie' sheet. I have currently managed to follow an example and use 1 variable (see copy).
Now I want 2 variables. Instead of just column K -> Completed, I also want to add that column J needs to be True!

```
function onEdit(event){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1per7L2wPkMKrzVgv5npQ-2RQ8fkWzslo09Ntlzy4qAs/edit?ts=6034e66e#gid=0";
  var source_sheet_name = "Werklijst";
  var target_sheet_name = "Historie";
  var columnLetter = "J";
  
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source_sheet_name);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name);
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(columnLetter+":"+columnLetter).getValues();
  
  for(var i = source_range.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
    if(source_range[i]=="COMPLETE"){
      var targetRange = target_sheet.getRange(target_sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      source_sheet.getRange((i+1), 1, 1, source_sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      source_sheet.deleteRow((i+1));
    }
  } 
}
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-OHJHvpQ2vjK8TqKFniu00p6YkONmC-GvXPNBtwTr38/edit?usp=sharing) to a copy of said sheet (it is in Dutch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to do something like that:

```
  var columnLetter1 = "K";
  var columnLetter2 = "J";
  var source_range1 = source_sheet.getRange(columnLetter1+":"+columnLetter1).getValues();
  var source_range2 = source_sheet.getRange(columnLetter2+":"+columnLetter2).getValues();
```

and then change the `if` statement to:

```
if(source_range1[i]=="COMPLETE" && source_range2[i]==true)
```

Full snippet of the user's code with the modification points:

```js
function onEdit(event){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1per7L2wPkMKrzVgv5npQ-2RQ8fkWzslo09Ntlzy4qAs/edit?ts=6034e66e#gid=0";
  var source_sheet_name = "Werklijst";
  var target_sheet_name = "Historie";
  var columnLetter1 = "K";
  var columnLetter2 = "J";

  
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source_sheet_name);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target_sheet_name);
  
  var source_range1 = source_sheet.getRange(columnLetter1+":"+columnLetter1).getValues();
  var source_range2 = source_sheet.getRange(columnLetter2+":"+columnLetter2).getValues(); 
  
  for(var i = source_range.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
    if(source_range1[i]=="COMPLETE" && source_range2[i]==true){
      var targetRange = target_sheet.getRange(target_sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      source_sheet.getRange((i+1), 1, 1, source_sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      source_sheet.deleteRow((i+1));
    }
  } 
}
```

Keep in mind that the current code is not very optimal since you don't use the [event object](https://www.google.com/search?q=event%20object%20google%20apps%20script&oq=event&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j46j0l2j69i60l2.2155j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) anywhere in your code. The latter will help you get info regarding the edits.

For example, right now your whole code will be executed upon every edit in any cell in the entire spreadsheet file. If you use the event object you can execute some code upon edits on a particular sheet (e.g. `Werklijst`) and on particular cells (e.g. cells in column K or J). In this way your code will be way faster and more efficient.

Comment: And how would one do that? I'm not a scripter / programmer. I barely scratched the surface here.